# Setting values for multi select elements in magento custom module

Tags: forms, magento, multi-select

I'm developing a custom module in magento and am having trouble defining options for multi select elemets

```
     $this->_addFieldsToFieldset($fieldset, array(           

        'cities' => array(
                'label' => $this->__('Cities'),
                'input' => 'multiselect',
                'required' => true,
                'options' => $zoneSingleton->getAvailableCities(),

        ),  
    ));
```

...and the getAvailableCities() is like,

```
    $read = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');        

    $results = $read->fetchAll("SELECT * from districts"); 

    $options = array();

    foreach($results as $row)
    {

            $options[$row['city_id']]  =    $row['city'];
    }       


    return $options;
    }
```

but the multi select element is shown but is not populated in the form. But if I were to set it as just a normal select element it gets populated. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else having the same issue

$this->_addFieldsToFieldset($fieldset, array(

```
    'cities' => array(
            'label' => $this->__('Cities'),
            'input' => 'multiselect',
            'required' => true,
            'values' => $zoneSingleton->getAvailableCities(),

    ),  
));
```

in the above options should be changes to values and the values array should be in the following format

```
 $options[]= array('value'=>$row['city_id'], 'label'=>$row['city']);
```